# threading. как закрыть поток извне

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Есть функция вида:

```
def thread_destruction(FORCED_CLOSURE_TIME=60):
    global current
    global invalid_urls
    global flag_forced_closure
    local_current = 0
    local_len_invalid_urls = len(invalid_urls)
    while flag_forced_closure != 1:
        time.sleep(FORCED_CLOSURE_TIME)
        if current != local_current or local_len_invalid_urls != len(invalid_urls):
            local_current = current
            local_len_invalid_urls = len(invalid_urls)
        else:
            flag_forced_closure = 1
            return()
```

которая проверяет, изменилась ли какая-нибудь переменная за 60 секунд. Если изменилась - меняет флаг и закрывается (вместе с ней и ее поток).
Этот флаг закрывает другие потоки.

Если я принудительно меняю флаг вне этой функции, то у меня останавливаются все потоки, кроме `Main` и потока функции `thread_destruction`, т.к. функция узнает об изменении флага не сразу, а по прошествии определенного времени, благодаря `time.sleep`.

Это крайне неприятно, т.к. я не могу дальше работать с программой, пока не истечет время. Как можно решить данную проблему? В документации `threading` нет инфы о закрытии потоков извне.

Answer (score 5):

Никак. Поток сам управляет собственным жизненным циклом. Вы можете только подавать ему сигналы через общую переменную или какой-либо примитив синхронизации. В частности, в вашем случае подошло бы ожидание [condition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) с таймаутом вместо `time.sleep`.

P.S. Глобальные переменные - сами по себе зло, а в многопоточном приложении - и вовсе безумие.